# Matching fields across multiple files

Tags: bash, awk, solaris, nawk

I have two files: file1 and file2 as follows:

```
file1                    file2
orangejuice              orangejuice_9.88_9.88
pineapplejuice           appleslices_6.3_2.2
appleslices              pineapplejuice_1.2_3.9
Mangojuice               Mangojuice_5.55_5.55
```

The output should be:

```
orangejuice_988
pineapplejuice_120_390
appleslices_630_220
Mangojuice_555
```

While reading line by line from file1, search for the pattern found in the line of file1 in file2, once found compare the 2nd and 3rd fields of file2 , if they are the same print it once, if not print the two numbers.(The number should be multiplied by 100 anyways)

I thought of this:

```
while read -r -u 3 line1
do
nawk ' "$line1" print $0}' file2.txt
if "$2" == "$3"
then echo "scale=2;$2*100" |bc
else echo "$2_$3"
fi
done 3<file1.txt
```

So, I want to know if the logic is correct and fix the multiplication that would give me 988 instead of 988.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way with `GNU awk`:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next}($1 in a){print $1,$2==$3?$2*100:$2*100OFS$3*100}' FS=_ OFS=_ file1 file2
orangejuice_988
appleslices_630_220
pineapplejuice_120_390
Mangojuice_555
```

Comment: No, the above code work perfectly with your input and `GNU awk`. Either you're not using `GNU awk` i.e. you have a Mac or your question  isn't representative of your actual data. `the above code is giving error` is completely useless to me, what error? What version or `awk` do you have? what system are you runing?

Comment: i have solaris so i'm using nawk

Comment: @user2613272 simply use `/usr/xpg4/bin/awk` instead then.

Comment: btw what does ($1 in a ) stand for ? precisely a

Comment: Is `$1` (the first field in the current record in file2) found in lookup array built from the first file i.e. is the first word in file2 found in file1. If that is all please accept this answer by clicking the tick mark next to it to shown your problem is solved.

Comment: I have a question what if file1 and file2 don't have same number of lines ; would the above code work?

Comment: Yes, that is not a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is much easier to express purely in Awk. Assuming the role of `file1` is to limit the data from `file2` to only some records (your example does not seem to demonstrate this), try something like this.

```
awk -F _ '# Make OFS equal to FS
    BEGIN { OFS=FS }
    # Read file1 into a[]
    NR==FNR { a[$0]++; next }
    # If we fall through to here, we are in file2
    # On any lines where $1 is in a[]
    a[$1] {
        if ($2==$3) print $1, $2*100;
        else print $1, $2*100, $3*100;
    }' file1 file2
```

Comment: I have one more question where can i store the output i usually use >> file3.txt but where can i place it ?

Comment: The above code doesn't give me any output when running the script

Comment: Works for me (modulo the OFS; fixed now); do you have invisible whitespace and/or aberrant line endings in your files?

Comment: i don't have any white spaces in my files

Comment: when i run the script, no errors show up yet , still there's no output being displayed. Can you think of any reason ? I tried echo instead of print it gave an error. please note i'm working in bash on solaris